# Add itemprop Schema.org Markup to li Elements in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, functions, menus, html

I currently call menus with a basic wp_nav_menu code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary') ); ?>
```

I am trying to find the easiest way to add `itemprop="url"` to the line elements for the purpose of Schema.org markup.  However, all of the codes I have found seem overly complex.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Is there a way to simply impact the line elements without impacting others menus?

Comment: So you know a code that works, so what is the problem? There is no such thing as easy code, just people with more and less knowledge in a specific domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add attributes to the menu's li elements, you'd have to write your own custom walker that extends the default Walker_Nav_Menu class (which is itself an extension of the Walker class). For more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

But as itemprop="url" should normally be added to anchor elements, you could use the [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes) filter.

For example, as per the WP docs, adding this to your functions.php will add the attribute itemprop="url" to your anchor elements within the list item elements of your menu:

```
function add_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  $atts['itemprop'] = 'url';
  return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
```